# Adding function gives error: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Just adding this function to a script gives the error `"too much recursion"`. The function is not called or executed.

```
function get_timezone_info() {

    var tz_info = determine_timezone();

    return tz_info;
}
```

How is that possible?

**Note:** putting the function into a `$(document).ready(function(){})` prevents the errror.

Comment: You should provide more context.

Comment: Simply adding that function to your code, if nothing calls it, absolutely will not cause a "too much recursion" error.

Comment: Pointy: I agree with you. Vohuman: I try to use the script from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pellepim/CsNcf/ to just retreive the data

Comment: Please, tell me why you downvote. If you ask me questions we could maybe find the solution to this. I'm not getting the error in Chromium, just in Firefox.

Comment: provide more details how u r calling the function and i have voted it up

Comment: Naveen Singh raghuvanshi: Thank you. I would like to call it from wihtin a document ready function, but the function is written outside this function. Firefox gives this error even if the function is not called. Ps. I've tried to simplify my example

Comment: Solution: I had accidently chosen the same name as another already existing function in the script. Changing the name to get_timezone_info2() made it work. Thank you to all of you with patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointy mentioned, if nothing calls it, it will not cause a "too much recursion" error.
There where already a function called get_timezone_info() in the script that was called and caused the error. The name was accidently chosen the same as another already existing function. Changing name from get_timezone_info() to get_timezone_info2() made it work.